# Can VS Code have a second activity bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code, custom-ui

I am coding in VS Code, ad I was wondering if there exists a way to collapse the second sidebar's icons like the primary one (with the activity bar) and keep them always visible. Is there a way to achieve this, maybe with an extension?

VS Code doesn't offer anything like a "Secondary activity bar" afaik, so I tried looking for an extension or UI customizer, but nothing would achieve what I was looking for.

[This is what i mean, in case my explaination is unclear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf8A2.png)

Comment: can you add a screenshot with a circle of what you're talking about for clarity?

Comment: I added an image visualizing the idea, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to find anything with VS Code vanilla. It was raised in a feature request, which was declined as out of scope: [Add Activity Bar Support for Secondary Sidebar #195561](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195561). See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195561#issuecomment-1764272128):

> We closed this issue because we [don't plan to address it](https://aka.ms/vscode-out-of-scope) in the foreseeable future. If you disagree and feel that this issue is crucial: we are happy to listen and to reconsider.

I can't say it's not possible for a UI customization to achieve this, but I think it would be a pretty difficult feat- especially if you wanted feature and behaviour parity.

Comment: well that's a bummer.. guess ill just switch over to Jetbrains' IDEs permanently

Comment: @AwMan3703 fyi, you can `"workbench.sideBar.location": "right",`, but that changes the primary sidebar position- not the secondary/auxiliary sidebar location.

Comment: i know, that was just not my idea